# How do I remove horizontal lines from Eclipse's (Kepler) text editors?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, customization, eclipse-kepler

Eclipse version: 4.3.2 (JEE, Win32 on Windows 7)
Plugins in use: Dump below.

The problem is the appearance of horizontal lines, making my editor look like a notebook.

[image: Problem]

I wasn't able to find a setting for disabling this. Here is my plugin dump:

[image]

Comment: What kind of editor is that in your screen shot? Eclipse's standard text editors don't do that, so it could be a different kind of file or one of those third-party plugins you have installed.

Comment: @E-Riz Believe it or not, it is a standard eclipse JS editor. The same problem exists with each and every editor, whether its text or xml or less or ruby, hardly makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting was in Jeeeyul's Themes. It has a section called editor, with the relevant setting shown below. Setting Underline Style to **None** got rid of those lines.

[image]